# apt-get update command not working in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

I am not able to update ubuntu 20.04 and getting below error

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:5 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                        
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease           
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                        
Hit:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease 
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Output from /etc/apt/sources.list :-
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to comment out the problematic line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with *cosmic* release and then retry with

```
sudo apt-get update
```